Is installing and running PostGIS (brew-version) with PostgreSQL (non-brew version) possible?
just for context I tried a couple of things to install PostGIS and nothing worked. So I'm using the PostgreSQL version 14.9 which I installed without homebrew, because I encountered some problems with the brew version (can't specifically name the problem as the installation was a couple months ago). For the management of my backend database I'm using pgAdmin 4 and the command "SELECT version();" gives me this output
"PostgreSQL 14.9 on x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9), 64-bit"
In my terminal the command "postgres --version" gives me this output
"postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.11 (Homebrew)"
That is the version I downloaded with brew but didn't uninstall it.
To install PostGIS I first did "brew install postgis" and with this it should work completely fine right? There is nothing else I need to do to install PostGIS that way? Nevertheless I realized something is wrong when I tried to "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;" with the brew version. First I got an error that said that the "postgis.control" file is missing. That's when I realized what exactly happens, because PostGIS was in the brew folder and the version of PostgreSQL that I'm using is in Macintosh HD/ Library. Even though the previously mentioned PostgreSQL (brew) version is still in the brew directory it wasn't able to create anything, which is fine because I'm not using that version.
I couldn't find anything remotely similar to my problem so I asked ChatGPT how to install PostGIS without brew. It gave me some instructions and I followed them.

I got the source code from their website
Placed the folder in the same directory as my PostgreSQL version (14.9)
And then Chat suggested me these steps

cd /path/to/postgis/source/code
./configure
make
sudo make install
After "./configure" the "make" command failed. Then I gave Chat the error and it suggested me to
"./configure --with-pgconfig=/path/to/your/postgresql/bin/pg_config (path to pg_config of PostgreSQL 14.9)"
apparently because the PostGIS file still searched in the brew folder. But still after the slightly changed "./configure" command I encounter error messages where it states that "libpq" wasn't found, even though it exists in the PostgreSQL (14.9) folder.
Furthermore while trying to configure, the terminal listed steps that suggest that the file is trying to configure with the brew version.
Things like

checking for msgmerge... /opt/homebrew/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgattrib... /opt/homebrew/bin/msgattrib
checking for msginit... /opt/homebrew/bin/msginit
checking for pkg-config... /opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes

So it is probably still trying to configure with the brew version? Do I have to change every path in the "configure.ac" file (the script used to configure)?
Is there no way to configure and install PostGIS without brew? Did anybody else encounter this (or a similar) problem?
Thanks in advance!
